# How can I turn this into a feature for my website?

Tags: html

I have made an animation/version of something on Scratch of what I wish to include in my website.

[Click here to view it](https://youtu.be/ztp2kMFrVTI)

As you can see by the video, the text appears in one state but then changes when the mouse is hovering over it and then turns green (confirmed as your choice) when you click on one of the options.
The reason why I wish to have this feature on my site is to see how people interpret things differently. I wish to see how people perceive the Bible by having this option for certain key-terms and verses and allow people to select what they think it means.

I am using Wix to make my website and they have an add-on which allows you to insert HTML code into the site so if there is a way to make this idea possible, that would be awesome.

It would mean a lot if I am able to understand how to do this and I would be extremely grateful.
Thanks

Comment: Please show the code that you've tried. Here is a link for how to ask questions on stackoverflow: https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Answer (score 0):

Wrap the text within a span and give it an id. You store this ID within the css file. Within this css file, call the ID and give it the background-color of yellow. When you hover over it, you will need jQuery. Research the mouse-in and mouse-out functions of jQuery.
Please send a link to your site if any more help is required.

```css
#nameofid{
    background-color: yellow;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

A working, **BASIC** example using `jQuery` and <s>`Tether.io`</s>.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en-US" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8" />
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-COMPATIBLE" content="IE=edge" />
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />

  <title>Choose an Option on Hover</title>



  <!-- <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/tether/1.4.0/css/tether.min.css" /> -->
  <style type="text/css" media="all">
    #selection {
      position: relative;
      background-color: yellow;
      display: inline-block;
    }

    #selection .options {
      position: absolute;
      z-index: 2;

      /* regulated using http://tether.io */
      left: 0;
      top: 100%;

      display: block;
      background-color: #454545;
      padding: 1rem;
      min-width: 150px;
    }

    #selection .options .option {
      display: block;
      background-color: black;
      color: #fff;
      padding: .35rem .7rem;
      margin-bottom: .7rem;
      cursor: pointer;

      border: 1px solid transparent;
    }

    #selection .options .option:hover {
      border: 1px solid #fff;      
    }

    #selection .options .option.choice {
      background-color: lime;
    }

  </style>
</head>
<body>
  <h1>Choose an Option on Hover</h1>



  <p>
    This is an example of html which I
    <span id="selection">
          <span class="display">Would</span>
          <span class="options">
            <button class="option" type="button" value="Option 1">Option 1</button>
            <button class="option" type="button" value="Option 2">Option 2</button>
          </span>
    </span>
    like to make.
  </p>



  <script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <!-- <script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/tether/1.4.0/js/tether.min.js"></script> -->
  <script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function() {
      var $selection = $('#selection');
      var $display = $selection.find('.display');
      var $options_container = $selection.find('.options');
      var $options = $selection.find('.option');

      $.each($options, function() {
        $(this).click(function() {
          var $choice = $(this);
          $display.text($choice.val());
          $choice.addClass('choice');
          $choice.siblings().removeClass('choice');
          $options_container.fadeOut();
        })
      });



      $selection.mouseover(function() {
        $options_container.fadeIn();
      });


      /*new Tether({
        element: $selection,
        target: $options_container,
        attachment: 'bottom left',
        targetAttachment: 'top left'
      });*/

      $options_container.fadeOut();

    });
  </script>
</body>
</html>
```